# Can't seem to replicate the Hausman test statistic without the phtest() function in R

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, panel-data, plm

I am trying to replicate the results of a Hausman test (random vs. fixed effects) in R without the function `phtest`. This works just fine with the help of the `vcov` function.

```
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")

form = inv ~ value + capital

wi = plm(form, Grunfeld, effect = "individual", model = "within")
rand = plm(form, Grunfeld, effect = "individual", model = "random")

q = wi$coefficients-rand$coefficients[2:3]
var_q = vcov(wi) - vcov(rand)[2:3,2:3]
(stat = t(q)%*%solve(var_q)%*%q)

phtest(form, Grunfeld, effect="individual")
```

However, when I try this by manually estimating the random effects model, the resulting test statistic is a bit off because $Cov(\hat \beta_{GLS})=(X'\Omega^{-1}X)^{-1}$ is marginally different to what `vcov(rand)` returns.

```
ervars = ercomp(form, Grunfeld, "individual")
sigma_mu = ervars$sigma2[2]
sigma_v = ervars$sigma2[1]
omega = sigma_mu*(diag(10)%x%matrix(1,20,20))+sigma_v*(diag(10)%x%diag(20))
X = cbind(1,Grunfeld[,4], Grunfeld[,5])
y = Grunfeld[,3]
re_gls = solve(t(X)%*%solve(omega)%*%X)%*%t(X)%*%solve(omega)%*%y
var_re_gls = solve(t(X)%*%solve(omega)%*%X)

q_alt = wi$coefficients-re_gls[2:3]
var_q_alt = vcov(wi) - var_re_gls[2:3,2:3]
(stat_alt = t(q_alt)%*%solve(var_q_alt)%*%q_alt)

var_re_gls
vcov(rand)
```

I assume that my estimation of $\Omega$ is not correct, but it is odd that the estimated coefficients are identical to the ones generated by the package. Does anyone know what leads to the small difference between $Cov(\hat \beta_{GLS})=(X'\Omega^{-1}X)^{-1}$ and `vcov(rand)`?